# ValueError: Tensor A must be from same graph as Tensor B

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator, tfrecord, variable-initialization

I am trying to run this ResNet with a few alterations.https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/resnet

After looking up the error, I understand the problem to be either :

1. That the tensors belong to different graphs, but I can't figure out how that came to be, as I'm not creating any graphs myself.
2. I have uninitialized variables in the parser function replacement.

If it's the initialization - How should I initialize them when using Estimator, which auto initializes and creates sessions?

This is the error:

```
ValueError: Tensor("IsVariableInitialized:0", shape=(), dtype=bool) must be from the same graph as Tensor("report_uninitialized_variables/IsVariableInitialized:0", shape=(), dtype=bool).
```

The entire code is very voluminous, so I'll only supply what I've made changes to (as it runs without these changes). Rest of the code is untouched (repo in the link above)

this is the original parser function(reads from binary files):

```
def parse_record(raw_record, is_training):
  """Parse CIFAR-10 image and label from a raw record."""
  # Convert bytes to a vector of uint8 that is record_bytes long.
  record_vector = tf.decode_raw(raw_record, tf.uint8)

  # The first byte represents the label, which we convert from uint8 to int32
  # and then to one-hot.
  label = tf.cast(record_vector[0], tf.int32)
  label = tf.one_hot(label, _NUM_CLASSES)

  # The remaining bytes after the label represent the image, which we reshape
  # from [depth * height * width] to [depth, height, width].
  depth_major = tf.reshape(record_vector[1:_RECORD_BYTES],
                       [_NUM_CHANNELS, _HEIGHT, _WIDTH])

  # Convert from [depth, height, width] to [height, width, depth], and cast as
  # float32.
  image = tf.cast(tf.transpose(depth_major, [1, 2, 0]), tf.float32)

  image = preprocess_image(image, is_training)

  return image, label
```

and this is my replacement to read from TFRecords:

```
def parse_record(raw_record, is_training):
  mode = 'train' if is_training else 'val'
  feature = {mode + '/image': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
           mode + '/label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)}
  filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([raw_record], num_epochs=1)
  reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
  _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
  features = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example, features=feature)
  label = tf.cast(features['train/label'], tf.int32)
  label = tf.one_hot(label, _NUM_CLASSES)
  image = tf.decode_raw(features['train/image'], tf.float32)
  image = tf.reshape(image, [_HEIGHT, _WIDTH, _NUM_CHANNELS])
  image = preprocess_image(image, is_training)
  return image, label
```

This is where the Estimator is created (I've not modified this bit)

```
def resnet_main(flags, model_function, input_function):
  """Shared main loop for ResNet Models."""

  # Using the Winograd non-fused algorithms provides a small performance boost.
  os.environ['TF_ENABLE_WINOGRAD_NONFUSED'] = '1'

  if flags.multi_gpu:
    validate_batch_size_for_multi_gpu(flags.batch_size)

    # There are two steps required if using multi-GPU: (1) wrap the model_fn,
    # and (2) wrap the optimizer. The first happens here, and (2) happens
    # in the model_fn itself when the optimizer is defined.
    model_function = tf.contrib.estimator.replicate_model_fn(
        model_function,
        loss_reduction=tf.losses.Reduction.MEAN)

  # Create session config based on values of inter_op_parallelism_threads and
  # intra_op_parallelism_threads. Note that we default to having
  # allow_soft_placement = True, which is required for multi-GPU and not
  # harmful for other modes.
  session_config = tf.ConfigProto(
      inter_op_parallelism_threads=flags.inter_op_parallelism_threads,
      intra_op_parallelism_threads=flags.intra_op_parallelism_threads,
      allow_soft_placement=True)

  # Set up a RunConfig to save checkpoint and set session config.
  run_config = tf.estimator.RunConfig().replace(save_checkpoints_secs=1e9,
                                                session_config=session_config)
  classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(
      model_fn=model_function, model_dir=flags.model_dir, config=run_config,
      params={
          'resnet_size': flags.resnet_size,
          'data_format': flags.data_format,
          'batch_size': flags.batch_size,
          'multi_gpu': flags.multi_gpu,
          'version': flags.version,
      })

  for _ in range(flags.train_epochs // flags.epochs_between_evals):
    train_hooks = hooks_helper.get_train_hooks(
        flags.hooks,
        batch_size=flags.batch_size,
        benchmark_log_dir=flags.benchmark_log_dir)

    print('Starting a training cycle.')

    def input_fn_train():
      return input_function(True, flags.data_dir, flags.batch_size,
                            flags.epochs_between_evals,
                            flags.num_parallel_calls, flags.multi_gpu)

    classifier.train(input_fn=input_fn_train, hooks=train_hooks,
                     max_steps=flags.max_train_steps)

    print('Starting to evaluate.')
    # Evaluate the model and print results
    def input_fn_eval():
      return input_function(False, flags.data_dir, flags.batch_size,
                            1, flags.num_parallel_calls, flags.multi_gpu)

    # flags.max_train_steps is generally associated with testing and profiling.
    # As a result it is frequently called with synthetic data, which will
    # iterate forever. Passing steps=flags.max_train_steps allows the eval
    # (which is generally unimportant in those circumstances) to terminate.
    # Note that eval will run for max_train_steps each loop, regardless of the
    # global_step count.
    eval_results = classifier.evaluate(input_fn=input_fn_eval,
                                       steps=flags.max_train_steps)
    print(eval_results)

    if flags.benchmark_log_dir is not None:
      benchmark_logger = logger.BenchmarkLogger(flags.benchmark_log_dir)
      benchmark_logger.log_estimator_evaluation_result(eval_results)
```